# Filtering a List using a separate List of values

Tags: c#, list, linq, filtering

I have a **List of Vehicles** with various fields such as registration, age, engine size, etc.  One of these fields is a **"tag"** field which in itself is a **List of tags**.

I am trying to filter this list of vehicles to only show the ones which include a tag which matches a value in a separate **neededTags list**.

I am trying to do this using Linq and Lambda expressions.

I have managed to get this working in situations where the Tag field in the main List is just a *normal string field*, NOT a list of strings.  The code for this is here:

```
filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(x => neededTags.Any(y => y == x.tags)).ToList();
```

where neededTags is my list of tags that I am interested in.

My problem now is that if the Tag element in the vehicles list is actually a list of tags then the compare element above says "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'List'"

I think I need to compare every element in the Vehicles Tag list with those in the neededTags list, but I just do not know how to do this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check if the *intersection* of the vehicle's list of tags and the list of needed tags has any elements (if there is at least on element in vehicle's tags that is also in needed tags):

```
filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => v.Tags.Intersect(neededTags).Any()).ToList();
```

If the vehicle's tag may be null, you can use the null-conditional operator

```
filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => v.Tags?.Intersect(neededTags).Any() == true).ToList();
```

Comment: This method also works, looks like there really is more than 1 way to skin a cat (not that I condone violent to animals in any way).

However, this also gives a similar error when the Vehicles Tag element is 'null'

Comment: @MikeL didn't know it  may be `null`... fixed my answer

Comment: sorry I had forgotten that the value could be 'null'

Anyway, all three answers worked, I tried them all, I had to add in the ? and =! null and == true bits to them to allow them to work with Nulls.

Excellent work, I truly did not think I would get an answer so quickly.  many thanks

I am marking this one as the correct answer as I am going to use this method going forward, but all of the first 3 answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a `string` to a list of `string`s for equality. Use the `.Contains` method to check for that:

```
// this is the short form for: .Where(x => neededTags.Any(y => x.tags.Contains(y)))
filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(x => neededTags.Any(x.tags.Contains)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Xiaoy312, this works a treat, I was so close as well. Thank you

However, I am getting at error in cases where a Vehicle record doesn't have any Tags and the tags element is null.  I don't suppose you know of a way around this do you?

I get the error "Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."

Answer (score 0):

I think Rene V has the best answer, but this also works and I've see it done this way in other posts. You can just use the Any method on both lists. I added test data also.

```
filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => (v.tags ?? new List<string>()).Any(t => neededTags.Any(n => n == t))).ToList();
```

Test Code:

```
var neededTags = new List<string> { "tag1", "tag2" };

var Vehicles = new[] {
    new {name = "vehicle1", tags = new List<string> { "tag1" } },
    new {name = "vehicle2", tags = new List<string> { "tag5" } }
            }.ToList();

var filteredVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => (v.tags ?? new List<string>()).Any(t => neededTags.Any(n => n == t))).ToList();
```